# "Table or view not found" error only from spark-submit but not spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The code logic is pretty simple, load data from `csv` and write into `hive`, hive table has been created before in `default` schema

```
CREATE TABLE datatable_01 (id INT, name STRING, ssn BIGINT, hours INT)
```

Code snippet below

```
val csvDataPath = "user/me/csvData"
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()
var csvDF = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(csvDataPath + "/result.csv").dropDuplicates()
csvDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("orc").option("header", "false").insertInto("default.datatable_01")
```

above code works fine from `spark-shell`

```
Spark version 2.3.0
Scala version 2.11.8
```

Not so much when deployed as Scala application via `spark-submit`

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>2.3.0</spark.version>
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
....
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
            <jvmArgs>
                <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
            </jvmArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

here is the mighty error message

```
19/08/27 08:50:49 ERROR QueryExecutionEventHandler: Action 'insertInto' execution failed 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: default.datatable_01;
```

I have seen threads talking about similar issue caused by using different version of Scala to build the application, but I think it is not my case. However for hours research I still can't find cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enabling Hive Support while building spark session using `.enableHiveSupport()`

If this doesn't work, also pass on configurations to your spark-submit to use catalog implementation `hive` and not its default `in-memory`.

You can use `spark.catalog` to debug to see what catalog is spark reading.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, `.enableHiveSupport()` did the job now no error from `spark-submit`, not sure why though. Case closed and thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

From Pom and code, can think of two reasons

1. spark-hive library missing in pom.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2. As @Vihit Shah suggested `.enableHiveSupport()` is missing

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("My_App").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
```

Let me know if doesn't work.

Comment: yes, `.enableHiveSupport()` did the trick, sorry have to mark Vihit's reply as answer as it's the first, still many thanks !

Comment: @Dreamer of course, No worries. Glad it got resolved.